# add composite/ foreign key in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a very basic question regarding the Keys in SQL. I am trying to write an SQL statement so I can add the foreign key to my tables, however, it would always "table not found or missing". And the reason why I can't create that table is that the next table also has foreign keys from another table that I need to reference. Is there a way around it?

```
create table table_name (id char (3) primary key, name varchar (8));

 SQL > table created.

create table table_name_2 (table2ID char (3) primary key, CID char (3), 
name varchar (8), title varchar (8), foreign key (CID) references table_name_3);

SQL > missing table (table_name_3);

create table table_name_3 (CID char (3) primary key, tTitle varchar (8), 
foreign key (phone) references table_name_4);
```

So I was only able to create table 3. What do I need to do so that I can create the table and add the foreign keys referencing while I write the SQL statements?

**I am not ALLOWED to use ALTER table.**

Comment: You have to first create the tables you reference, so in this case 3 must come before 2. Or you have to add the foreign keys in the end.

Comment: Well I would do that right, but table_3 also has foreign keys referencing other tables. How would I add foreign keys after? Do you mean I add the attributes in the table and declared foreign keys once all tables are created?

Comment: Yes, just declare table structure first and when all tables are done then add the foreign keys with `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen umm I was asked not to use the alter table. Is there another way around it?

Comment: If there are cycles in the table relationships, then you have no choice but to create the tables first, and then to use ALTER TABLE. For example: 2 tables for employees and departments; employees have foreign key to department id, and departments have foreign key to employee id of the department manager. However, if there are no cycles (like the example I just gave), then you can do everything just with CREATE TABLE statements - you just must do that in the right order. Start with a table that has NO FOREIGN KEYS. (There will be at least one, if there are no circular references!) Then proceed.

Comment: @mathguy OHHH i see, so then I would have to figure out the right order and make sure it doesn't interfere with it. Thank you

Comment: @mathguy If i had one foreign key that belonged to the same table, how would my statement look like? would it be similar to "primary key" but without references? like the same foreign key in the SAME table?

Comment: @user372204 - no; alas, that is an example of a cycle (of length 1) - as you would have in a graph, with an edge looping from one node back to itself. It's still a cycle, and you can only define the foreign key after the fact (after you create the table); you will need to use ALTER TABLE for that. If you have that situation and you were told not to use ALTER TABLE, then whoever asked you to do that has no clue what they are talking about.

Comment: I would really _really_  REALLY push back on the 'no alter table' pseudo-requirement.  It makes no sense at all.  Unless this is actually a homework assignment for which the entire purpose is to get you to think more deeply about relationships and prerequisites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create foreign keys **separately**, using the ALTER TABLE statement. Like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_name(
  2    id    CHAR(3)PRIMARY KEY,
  3    name  VARCHAR(8)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table_name_2(
  2    table2id  CHAR(3)PRIMARY KEY,
  3    cid       CHAR(3),
  4    name      VARCHAR(8),
  5    title     VARCHAR(8)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table_name_3(
  2    cid     CHAR(3)PRIMARY KEY,
  3    ttitle  VARCHAR(8)
  4  );

Table created.
```

Now the foreign key:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE table_name_2 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_2_3 FOREIGN KEY(cid)
  2    REFERENCES table_name_3;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: umm I was asked not to use the alter table. Is there another way around it?

Comment: Certainly. Create tables that will be referenced by foreign keys first, then create table which reference previously created tables. That's usually possible, but will **not** be if there's a cross-reference between two (or more) tables, i.e. the ones that reference each other. You can't fix that other than creating the foreign key constraint separately.

Answer (score 0):

one approach you can od is to create the table with the Primary key and then do
and add the foreign key.

ALTER TABLE child_table
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES parent_table(col1);

Comment: umm I was asked not to use the alter table. Is there another way around it?